# How can I programatically clear the search fields in smart-table?

Tags: smart-table

I'm using smart-table at the moment, and I have input text boxes up the top of each column and I am using st-search.  The point of what I am making is something is selected from the table, and then the results in the table are changed.

I am trying to clear the search boxes when the row is clicked.  At the moment other business logic is implemented on click, so it's at this point that I am looking to clear these text boxes.

I have tried to associate an ng-model to these text boxes, and to clear them when the row is clicked but the text boxes don't change.  I have also googled this issue and I have only found solutions on how to make this work for when you click on a button (by a directive) to clear the predicates.  I haven't been able to make these solutions work programatically however.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I did the following:

1. Monkey-patched smarttable.js with the code in this github issue (https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/164).  For me this occured at around line 574.

   // added from https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/164
       ng.module("smart-table").directive("stResetSearch",
           function() {
               return {
                   restrict: 'EA',
                   require: '^stTable',
                   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                       return element.bind('click',
                           function() {
                               return scope.$apply(function() {
                                   var tableState;
                                   tableState = ctrl.tableState();
                                   tableState.search.predicateObject = {};
                                   tableState.pagination.start = 0;
                                   return ctrl.pipe();
                               });
                           });
                   }
               };
           });

   2. Added 'st-research-search' to the element that was calling the function in angularjs. For me, that was the "tr" element.  Like below.

      ```
           <tr ng-repeat="medicine in medicines" ng-click="medicationMatched(medicine)" ng-class="heatmapClass(medicine)" st-reset-search>
      ```

This worked fine.  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to programatically clear the predicates from the code.  But this works well enough for me.